# How to merge a duplicated code, one instance being in PHP the other one with Doctrine Query Builder?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine.

**I have a `Foo` object, which is a Doctrine entity. In this object, I need to have an information named `bar` which I get through a long computation from the entity attributes** (i.e. DB fields).

The (short version of the) code looks like that:

```
class Foo {

    public __construct() {
        computeBarValue();
    }

    private computeBarValue() {
        $this->bar = /*long computation from other attributes*/ ;
    }
}
```

But now, it happens **I also need this computation to filter the results of some of the requests I make to Doctrine**. This can be written like this:

```
class FooRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function myFilteredQuery() {
        //...
        $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('a')
            ->from($this->_entityName, 'a')
            ->where( /*long computation from other fields*/ );
        //...
   }
}
```

The thing is, **since the computation code is long and complex and might change in the future, I do not want to duplicate it** with one occurence in the Entity and another one in the query builder definition (as showed above). I've searched if it is possible to add 'virtual' calculated columns with Doctrine (here I would add a `bar` column) but this seems to be impossible.

Is there a way to merge/factorize all this?

Answer (score 1):

`Entities` are just `data-holders`, anything about query should go into `repositories`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you cannot factorize the same code from 2 different langages (PHP and SQL). It's like if you wanted to factorize in the same function a PHP and a Javascript code.

The closest possibility with Doctrine is to define a custom DQL function, with PHP code inside, but it won't be pure SQL : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve, I can't be certain, but maybe [Doctrine criteria](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) might be what you're looking for.